# angular group module references in a single module

Tags: angular, reference, angular-module

My application has a number of modules users may reference before they decide to sign-up.  I want to keep them separate from others.

These "PreRegistration" modules would be then lazy loaded.
Directory PreRegistration has a splash-page module (and eventually others) that are all referenced by the pre-reg.module.ts:

[image]

pre-reg module is the collection of all PreRegistration modules (only 1 in this case):

[image]

In this simple case, I want to show it in the app.component.html so I import in AppModule:

[image]

But in app.component.html, the splash-page selector is not recognized. 
SplashPageComponent has no functions, just a dummy html.

[image]

but the selector is correct.  Here is app.component.html complaining about the missing reference?

[image]

My "cute" organization seems to be a waste of time.
Any ideas why it isn't being referenced?
THANKS IN ADVANCE.  :-)  Yogi

Comment: just to be sure you have declared `SplashPageComponent` in `SplashPageModule` and added it to exports there also maybe you can prepare example on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you are missing here:

1. You need to *declare* the component in the module, so that angular is
   aware of it
2. To use a component *outside* its declared module, you need to export it in the module so that it can be used elsewhere.

splash-page.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [SpashScreenComponent, ....],
   exports: [SpashScreenComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you forgot to export SpashPageComponent in SplashPageModule.

splash-page.module.ts
...

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [SpashScreenComponent, ....],
exports: [SpashScreenComponent]
})
```

Comment: I am sooo embarrassed.  I have made that SAME mistake since Angular 2!  I even have a sign on my wall; (I just don't read it LOL).  Thank you so much,